# android:pathPattern не работает

Tags: android, manifest, pathpattern

Нужно перехватывать приложением ссылки, вида https://test.ru/user/password?hash=[some_letters_and_numbers]
Прописал в манифесте:
`<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="test.ru"
    android:pathPattern="/user/password?hash=.*\\" />`
По идее должен перехватывать только ссылки следующего вида:
https://test.ru/user/password?hash=54huhe4543t
Но перехватывает любую ссылку на домене https://test.ru
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на `pathPrefix` и убрать всё после `=`. И ещё, это у Вас единственный блок `<data>` с этим хостом?

Comment: А вообще-то знак вопроса и всё что после - это уже не path, а query. Возможно из-за этого паттерн игнорируется или неправильно обрабатывается.

Comment: @woesss Вы правы. Вопрос и всё что после пришлось убрать, с ними ни в какую не работало. А ещё интересная особенность проявилась. Описал в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У данного *intent-filter* было 2 блока *data*
`<data
    android:host="auth"
    android:pathPattern="/.*"
    android:scheme="testscheme" />`
`<data
    android:host="test.ru"
    android:pathPrefix="/user/password"
    android:scheme="https" />`

При таком раскладе перехватывались все ссылки вида [https://test.ru/[что_угодно]](https://test.ru/[%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE])
Если же разделить эти два блока *data* по разным *intent-filter*, тогда работает всё как надо. Как будто pathPattern привязывается не к схеме+хосту, а к *intent-filter*.
Будет здорово, если кто-то сможет описать почему так происходит.

Comment: В [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element) написано, что в один фильтр входят все атрибуты всех блоков `<data>`. То есть разницы нет: будут они все в одном блоке, в двух или каждый в своём.